# "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'cursor"

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, flask

```
connection = request.form.get('connection_type_id')
tariff = request.form.get('tariff_id')

house = request.form.get('house_type_id')

status = 1

mySql_insert_query = "INSERT INTO tbl_consumer(consumer_no, connection_type_id, tariff_id, house_type_id, status) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"

cursor = connection.cursor()

result = cursor.execute(mySql_insert_query,(consumer, connection, tariff, house, status))

connection.commit()

print("Record inserted successfully into Laptop table")

cursor.close()

return redirect(url_for('admin_add_consumer'))
```

Comment: please always post the full traceback of the error so that it becomes clear which line exactly throws the error.

Comment: Try to list your issue clearly with relevant code block and stack trace.

Comment: From the code, connection is a type of str. This is why it errors when calling cursor function on connection.

Answer (score 0):

`connection = request.form.get('connection_type_id')` was this supposed to be connection_type_id = ....? `request.form` is by default `ImmutableMultiDict` with form data, your connection variable is set to form element with name connection_type_id, that's why you are getting error. I assume connection is mysql connection object from global space.

Please change to `connection_type_id = request.form.get('connection_type_id')` and it's references as well.